# Why Do My HTTP Headers only apply to sub-documents?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I have created an htaccess file for my multi-site Wordpress website, which contains the standard rewrite rules followed by a mod_headers section, with conditional FilesMatch directives.

The http headers all apply correctly to subdocuments of any Wordpress page (e.g. png, jpg, js, css etc), but **never** apply to the root document. Another pure html site on the same host does receive the headers correctly.

For example:
    `https://www.somedomain.com/site.css`
returns:

```
    HTTP/2 200 OK
    content-type: text/css
    date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 09:36:10 GMT
    server: Apache
    x-content-type-options: nosniff
    last-modified: Sun, 29 Mar 2020 12:55:43 GMT
    etag: "14546d-5a1fdda3e88c5-gzip"
    accept-ranges: bytes
    cache-control: must-revalidate, public, max-age=31536000
    expires: Sat, 20 Mar 2021 09:36:10 GMT
    vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    content-encoding: gzip
```

but `https://www.somedomain.com/` only returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 30 Mar 2020 09:36:09 GMT
server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/7.3.16
cache-control: no-cache
content-encoding: gzip
```

The htaccess code is below:

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) web/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ web/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress

#BEGIN Headers
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
#Remove server headers
    Header always unset X-Redirect-By
    Header always unset X-Powered-By
    Header always unset Location
#Set server headers
    Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    Header append Vary "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent"
#Set Cache-Control
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|svg|webp|swf|css|mp4)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "must-revalidate, public, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|x?html?|pdf|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|zipx?)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
#PHP/HTML specific headers
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|x?html?)$">
        Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
        Header always set X-DNS-Prefetch-Control "on"
        Header always set Connection "keep-alive"
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        Header always set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
        Header always set X-Clacks-Overhead "GNU Terry Pratchett"
    </FilesMatch>
 </IfModule>
#END Headers
```

Comment: Because `/` isn’t a static file delivered by just the webserver on its own, but gets served by WordPress itself …? (For any _actual_ WP page or post, I am guessing it won’t work either?) Any of your header configurations that refer to a specific file type do nothing here to begin with, and the rest that you are trying to set for “everything”, might get partially overwritten by WP.

Comment: Hi @CBroe,
Thanks, yes, I did wonder if that might be the case.However, I have also tested the code on my local webserver running an instance of Wordpress with a similar configuration (albeit not multisite), and the headers are correctly sent.

Comment: Then it might be a different issue after all. Perhaps on your live server, you might not be _allowed_ to specify all those headers. Your hoster might set their own defaults, maybe even have them override the ones you are trying to set.